# How to setState in AsyncStorage block with react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want **setState** in **AsyncStorage** block but there is a error: **undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.setState')**.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        activeID:this.props.data.channel[0].id
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.type,function(errs,result){
        if (!errs) {
            if (result !== null) {
                this.setState({activeID:result});
            }
        }
    });
}

_buttonPressed = (id,name,index) => {
    this.setState({activeID:id});

    AsyncStorage.setItem(this.props.data.type,id,function(errs){
     if (errs) {
       console.log('error');
     }
     if (!errs) {
       console.log('succeed');
     }
 });
}
```

Any help will be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a binding issue. Try the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.type, (errs,result) => {
        if (!errs) {
            if (result !== null) {
                this.setState({activeID:result});
            }
         }
    })
 }
```

The reason for this is that functions declared with the `function` specifier create a context of their own, that is, the value of `this` is not the instance of your component. But "fat arrow" functions do not create a new context, and so you can use all methods inside. You could as well `bind` the function in order to keep the context, but in this case I think that this solution is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to react native and js. I find another solution, but it's a bit complicated.

Comment: Yours is also a very nice solution, particularly if you have a lot of Promises chained one after the other :D

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution, but **martinarroyo**'s answer is much more cleaner.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
}

async _loadInitialState(){
    try{
        var value=await AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.type);
        if(value!=null){
            this._saveActiveID(value);
        }
    } catch(error){

    }
}
_saveActiveID(id) {
    this.setState({activeID: id});
}
```